# Stein's Complex Analysis Page 46 Theorem 4.1

Tags: complex-analysis

In the proof of the Theorem 4.1 in the Stein's Complex Analysis book, he first constructed a keyhole. Then by previous knowledge, the integral of $F$ along the boundary of keyhole is zero. Then he said: make the corridor narrower by letting the $\delta$ tend to $0$, and use the continuity of $F$ to see that in the limit, the integrals over the two sides of the corridor cancel out...

I don't understand why while letting $\delta$ tend to $0$, the Integral can still keep $0$. It seems that additional conditions are needed. For example, something like 'uniformly convergence' to allow the interchange of integration and limiting.

Let me explain what I am confused about: for example, I integral an entire function $f(z)$ from $-1+iy$ to $1+iy$ horizontally (called the segment $T_y$). So $\int_{T_y}f(z)dz=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x+iy)dx$. But however, I cannot deduce that $\int_{T_{y}}f(z)dz\rightarrow\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$ as $y\rightarrow 0$.

So similarly, I don't think we can get $\int_{\varGamma_{0,\epsilon}}F(\zeta)d\zeta=0$...
[image: Proof]
[image: Theorem]

Comment: Oh, I think there is a same question...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75824/justifying-taking-the-limit-of-a-keyhole-contour?rq=1

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. You need uniform continuity. Do you know the following theorem?

> The Heine–Cantor theorem: Every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Now to solve your problem:

The function $f$ is continuous on the solid rectangle containing both lines and  the rectangle is compact, thus $f$ is uniformly continous on the rectangle. Now using uniform continuity, for $y$ small you can write $ f(x+iy) = f(x) + \epsilon(x,y) $ and $|\epsilon(x,y)|\to 0$ as $y \to 0$.

Now $$\left|\int (f(x+iy)-f(x))dx\right| \le \int \left|f(x+iy) -f(x)\right|dx = \int |\epsilon(x,y)|dx,$$

and by choosing $y$ small you can make the last integral as small as you want.

**Heads up:** Because of continuity, the values of the two integrals are within $\epsilon$ of one another, and so in the limit they are equal, but their values are not necessarily zero.