# Prove that shifted integral along path converges

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : C → C$ be continuous. For ε ≥ 0 consider the paths $γ_{ε,R}:[0, R] → C, γ_{ε,R}(t) = t + iε$.

If $γ$ is the path $γ_{0,R}$ show that $$\int_{γ_{ε,R}} f(z) dz→\int_{γ} f(z) dz$$

as $ε → 0$ .

I've been thinking about this question for ages and I feel as though I'm overthinking it. I understand it to be a rectangular contour? I'm new to complex analysis, so I'm not sure whether it's just asking to prove that you can take keyhole contours, or if it's some sort of lemma before proving that one and I'm not understanding the question.

For example, is it just asking the same thing as page 12 of this pdf?
[https://services.math.duke.edu/~jtwong/math551-2019/lectures/ComplexVariables2_techniques.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ejtwong/math551-2019/lectures/ComplexVariables2_techniques.pdf)

Or this thread?
[Justifying taking the limit of a keyhole contour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75824/justifying-taking-the-limit-of-a-keyhole-contour)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use uniform continuity of $f$ on comoact sets to estimate the difference of the integrals.